# Move MySql data from two columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql, set

I have a database with multiple columns that represent the same type of data. To slim down the db and make it easier for future use I want to merge data from these columns into one. My problem is I don't know the SQL for this operation. Most of the search-hits for this only provide me with resultsets, but I want to make permanent changes to the database.

I know how to update between two columns, but not how to move data from multiple columns into one.

So far I have tried this

```
    UPDATE db SET firm = firm_stone AND firm_concrete
```

And

```
    UPDATE db SET firm = firm_stone, firm_concrete
```

And

```
    UPDATE db SET `firm` = `firm_stone`, `firm_concrete`
```

This SQL is clearly wrong as it gives me this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the two columns ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `firm_stone + firm_concrete` ?

Comment: @ChrVik if my answer is useful to you, plz add the tick mark on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate these 2 column's value to a single string to keep that in a same column.

```
UPDATE db.tablename SET firm = concat_ws(' ',firm_stone, firm_concrete);
```

here `' '` a blank space will be placed with the 2 strings. You can use your own.

Comment: Works!, thank you for helping out!

Comment: You are welcome @ChrVik.

Comment: Just a little follow up, if I may. How can I concat from another column without deleting data? I found another column that also needs added to firm, but I am afraid some data from the previous operation will be overwritten with zero values.

Comment: `concat_ws()` method allows more than 2 or 3 value to concat, and handle null by himself. And no data or column value will be deleted until you have run any delete sql. And more impotently don't be afraid just keep experiment with sample tables and see what actually happens.